# Treating dot symbols as a username string in url

Tags: python, django

The url forwards to the right page, but on the page it gives a 404 error when the username has a dot. Is there a way to handle this, or should I forward to ID instead? What is the proper way to do this?

url.py

```
url(r'profile/(?P<username>[-\w.]+)$', views.get_user_profile, name='user_profile'),
```

views.py

```
def get_user_profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    render (request, 'pages/user_profile.html', {"user":user})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py:

```
url(r'profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.get_user_profile, name='user_profile)
```

in views:

```
def get_user_profile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    render (request, 'pages/user_profile.html', {"user":user})
```

The alternative would be to send the username as a get parameter:

www.yourapp.com?username=abc

Then in views:

```
def get_user_profile(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)  # need to catch error if not found
    render (request, 'pages/user_profile.html', {"user":user})
```

Comment: im not asking for an user. this is to view all users